# how does passport.js check cookies?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, session-cookies

I am having troubles understanding how passport.js authentication flow works.

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  done(null, id);
});

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: 'session',
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [config.COOKIE_KEY_1, config.COOKIE_KEY_2],
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// this is a middleware for my protected routes
const checkLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  const isLoggedIn = req.isAuthenticated() && req.user;
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: 'you muse log in!',
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

I have read a few articles. They say the "user.id" in passport.serialize is stored in req.session & the "id" in passport.deserialize is the same as "user.id".
My questions are:

1. is "user.id" sent to the browser along with the cookie?
2. How does passport verify cookie when there is a request to the server to get the id out of it?
3. Does the client know about "req.session" & can the client access this data?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the session are only known to the server and are always available in `req.session`. A cookie is sent between server and client which ensures that `req.session` is always the session that belongs to the client that sent the request `req`. In other words: When the code on your server accesses `req.session`, it will always access the session contents of the user who made the current request.

But the session contents are not accessible by the client (and nor is the session cookie if it is configured as [`httpOnly`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#user-content-cookie)).

So the answers to your questions are:

1. No
2. Don't know details, but passport can access `req.session.user.id`
3. No

Comment: What if I have multiple users? Does passport store all user.id in req.session as an array?

Comment: Two users would use two different browsers, hence they would have different cookies, hence their requests would lead to different values of `req.session`, each with one user in it. If two users sit in front of the same browser and both try to log on (in two different browser tabs, say), that will not work.